# Yukon giant mountain bike

Tags: mountain-bike

I have a Yukon Giant mountain bike, serial number GN2L7542. I would like to know the year it was manufactured and how much it is worth.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE.I'm sorry, we don't do valuations. You can find out more about how our site works by taking our [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Sorry - we don't do valuations here.  Its worth whatever someone is prepared to pay for it.

Google suggests the model existed from 2005 through to present day.

The serial number is generally useless for figuring out anything, other than warranty tracking.  You might get some info from Giant directly, using their contact information at https://www.giant-bicycles.com/contact/